# Sorting by Line-Item Attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an unordered list that is rendered with random letter values:

```
<ul class="answers">
   <li class="answer" letter-value="D" data-answer-id="3">D  4 Members</li>
   <li class="answer" letter-value="C" data-answer-id="2">C  7 Members</li>
   <li class="answer" letter-value="A" data-answer-id="4">A  Zero</li>
   <li class="answer" letter-value="B" data-answer-id="1">B  2 Members</li>    
</ul>
```

Is there a way to sort this list by the letter-value attribute so I can have the answers displayed in alphabetical order?

Comment: Thanks for the reference, RGraham. I did not come across that post before.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0pzcr4rx/